# Google Places AutoComplete - Clicking on link makes a function run

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I have an input field that uses google places autocomplete. At the top of the dropdown menu that appears when a user types a location, I added a link saying "Can't find address?"

[image]

**What I want to accomplish:**

When the user clicks on "can't find address?", I want a few input fields to appear, as such[image]

(*I got this image and idea from eventbrite*)

I want those fields to appear right below the event location input field.

My idea is that I would just add a hidden class (display: none) to those input fields, and when the user clicks "can't find address", I'd remove the class. In theory, that should work.

However, I can't seem to figure out how to recognize that the user clicked the link. I tried to simplify the problem by simply outputting "Clicked!" when the user clicks "can't find address". But even that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="location">Event Location</label>
    <input name="location" type="text" class="form-control" id="location" placeholder="Hogwarts School, 127 Long Island">
</div>
<script>
          var ac = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('location'));
          ac.addListener('place_changed', function() {
              var place = ac.getPlace();                 
          });
          $('#location').on('click', function() {
                var picklist = $('.pac-container');
                var link = picklist.find('a');
                if(link.length === 0) {
                    picklist.append("<div class='pac-item'><a class='toggle'><div class='pac-icon'></div> Can't find address?</a></div>");
                    $('.toggle').on('click',  function() {
                          console.log("clicked!");

                    });
                }
          });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out! Thanks so much for your help.

So basically, when I tried anonymous' fiddle on the phone, it worked. In other words 'click touchstart' was recognized. On my laptop, I replaced 'click touchstart' that with 'mouseover', then hovered over "can't find address". It worked - the hover was detected. Which means that the event 'click' wasn't registering.

So I looked at the mdn event reference.

click: A pointing device button (ANY button) has been pressed and released on an element.

The problem is that as soon as a mouse is pressed, the pac-container is removed. In other words, you don't get a click and release.

So instead of using 'click', I used the 'mousedown' event, which only requires a mousepress. And it worked

```
$(document).on('mousedown', '.toggle',function() {
      console.log("clicked!"); 
      alert("HI");
      $('.pac-container').remove();
});
```

Comment: Nice find .. I thought it is removed after full process "down" ,"up" and "click"

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that autocomplete internally clones whatever html you pass in so event handlers gets removed but you can use bubbling to delegate click for `'.toggle'` on some root node like `<body` , `<html>` or `document` object itself .To avoid memory leaks i would suggest placingyour handler outside of `$('#location').on('click', {.....})`

Try this

```
   $(document).on('click', '.toggle',function() {
          console.log("clicked!"); 
   });
```

Comment: Are you trying this on a phone? If so then you need touch events as wel to work with overlays .Anyway have a look [here](https://jsfiddle.net/1qaeb5fn/) make necessary changes

Comment: Figured it out! Thanks so much for your help.